# How do I disable the 'open' command, knowing that it is just a link to the 'openvt' binary?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, alias

I'd like users to be able to install my command line tool...

https://github.com/occam-proof-assistant/Open-CLI

...globally and run it from the terminal by typing `open`. The NodeJS package manager, `npm`, provides this facility, creating the necessary symbolic link when you install packages globally. So in the `/usr/bin` directory, I see the following symbolic link has indeed been created:

```
open -> ../lib/node_modules/occam-open-cli/open.js
```

However, this only works if I'm root, otherwise I get:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

I know what this is, sort of. If I type `openvt`, I get the same message.

So I need to be able to delete the alias, or whatever, that allows `openvt` to be invoked with `open`. I think this is a safe thing to do, since you can always just fall back to typing `openvt` if you want to.

However, I'm at a loss to find a way to do this. I'd assumed that there was some kind of alias, but typing `unalias open` didn't work.

So what/where is this mystery `open` command, alias, symbolic link or whatever? And how can I safely remove it, and advise others to do the same?

Comment: I might be misreading your question, but if you type `type -a open`, it should show you all the things that `open` means to the shell

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. I get `/usr/bin/open` and `/bin/open`. I'll investigate what this are, whether links or binaries...

Comment: Done it! Deleting the `open -> openvt` symbolic link in the `/bin` directory did it and I reckon it's perfectly safe to tell others to do the same.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, maybe you should try avoiding using such a generic name for your tool. The fact that you are deleting symlinks that are default on your system already means that someone used to using such a symlink that installs your product is going to see some frustrations. Let alone the fact that someone else may come up with another utility and want to use simply ```open``` as the command as well.

Comment: Those symlinks are installed by the system package manager, you potentially just broke your users system. Manually deleting symlinks is not a solution I would accept for a program unless it was very early development and I was participating.

Comment: @BrianSizemore and @crasic are right. You're asking for trouble using a name that's so generic. There's a pretty high likelihood of users having an alias or shell function named `open` that wraps commonly-used commands. As like @Zanna said, aliases will always take precedence over other commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that `/bin/open` takes precedence over `/usr/bin/open` on your system is presumably that `/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in your PATH. To examine your PATH, you can run `echo $PATH`. The elements are separated with colons.

You got the command you wanted when you used (I assume) `sudo` to run `open` or to start a root shell in which you ran it, because `sudo` uses its own PATH, defined in `/etc/sudoers` as `secure_path`, which on my system is

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

As you can see, `/usr/bin` comes before `/bin`.

I think your finding is odd, because as far as I know, `/usr/bin` usually comes before `/bin`. Your users may not have the same problem as you.

However, to be safe, you could have your program be installed in `/usr/local/bin`, which should always come before `/usr/bin` and `/bin` in a user's PATH so that software built locally takes precedence over other commands with the same name.

Even safer, as [steeldriver suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018316/how-do-i-disable-the-open-command-knowing-that-it-is-just-a-link-to-the-open?noredirect=1#comment1652577_1018321), have your users (or your installation script) define an alias for your tool in a shell configuration file such as `~/.bashrc`. Aliases always take precedence over other commands. By putting an alias in your `~/.bashrc` you ensure that it will only be known to interactive shells, and will not interfere with other programs.

Deleting the symlink could cause problems if programs try to execute `/bin/open` expecting `openvt`, and may be unreliable, as pointed out by steeldriver, because the symlink might be recreated when the package that provides it is updated or reinstalled (i.e. fairly unpredictably).

Comment: I think that's a very good point. I'll try to create a link in my own .bashrc file and when I've got it right, I advise that others to the same.

Comment: That worked! I put the symbolic link back first, then added the alias and all is well.

Comment: @JamesSmith great! Maybe you want to edit your own answer to show your updated solution (where you put the alias and your assignment etc)

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

In fact there was a symbolic link `open -> openvt` in the `/bin` directory. Removing this link fixed the problem. However, by far the best solution, as mentioned elsewhere, is to create an alias on your `.bashrc` file...

Navigate to your home directory:

```
cd ~
```

Edit your `.bashrc` (here I've used `nano` but there plenty of options):

```
nano .bashrc
```

Put the following somewhere (perhaps at the foot):

```
alias open='/usr/lib/node_modules/occam-open-cli/open.js'
```

You can reload the file by typing `source .bashrc` and you're good to go without affecting anything else.

Comment: This is interesting, because I think `/bin` comes *after* `/usr/bin` in the default PATH. If you look at the `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers` you should see that `/usr/bin` comes before `/bin`, and that's why you got the command you wanted with `sudo` (assuming you used `sudo` to run the command or open a root shell). Rather than deleting the symlink, check your PATH. Perhaps you should get your tool to install in `/usr/local/bin` which is always before `/usr/bin` and `/bin` in the default PATH. Hmm. Perhaps this comment is an answer... Still, +1...

Comment: @Zanna yes please make that an answer - perhaps creating an alias would be even better (since that won't mess with non-interactive environments that may expect `open` to be `openvt`). IMHO removing the symlink is the worst solution of the three - if the package that created it (package `kbd` iirc) gets updated or re-installed, there's a good chance the link will get re-created.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks a lot! I have used your insights in my answer, assuming you didn't want to write one...

Comment: @Zanna I missed the part about the path order - your answer is spot on IMHO